# css3 keyframes animation is not working for unknown reason

Tags: css, animation

This is weird. seems like i have got all the syntax correct. Still not working as expected on any browser? any help?

btw: I know about -moz,-webkit, -o prefix stuff. I also tried with those. It's just isn't working

I want a slow bounce effect. Here's my complete [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blueclue/RaXgq/6/)

```
div {
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    animation:glide 5s linear 2s ease-in-out alternate;
}

@keyframes glide {
    from {left:0px; top:0px;}
    to {left:0px; top:20px;}
}
```

Comment: btw no need for <style> in jsfiddle in the css section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation declaration is a bit messy. You have to declare only one timing, one easing and so on... For example you're declaring `5s` and then `2s`, and then two different easings.

Here's a working fiddle (view in Chrome/Safari): http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/RaXgq/10/

Comment: Wow..this is exactly what I'm looking for. And thanks for pointing out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation:glide 5s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes glide {
    from {left:0px; top:0px;}
    to {left:0px; top:120px;}
}
```

works great.

Comment: I haven't still got it working. Beside, did you have a look at my jsFiddle? I'm using an image element inside html div tag. Not sure what's the role of 'inline-block' in your CSS suggestion.

Comment: sorry, my bad, your code is working great! But sill confuse about "inline-block" , why the image itself can't do the trick?